# How to print solutions in exsheets correctly when using parts and restarting chapter numbers?

Tags: exsheets

I have a document with questions and solutions with multiple parts and I set the chapter numbers to reset at each part. I want to show the solutions of a chapter at the end of the chapter. Unfortunately the solutions are not shown correctly. In the following MWE you will notice that the solution for question 1 of part 1 is also shown in part 2. Any idea how to solve this easily? It is ok if the question numbers also restart at each chapter, but I left that out of the MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets}[2015/07/04]
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\part{part1}
\chapter{chap1part1}
\begin{question}
    What is 1+1
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    2
\end{solution}
\printsolutions[chapter]
\part{part2}
\chapter{chap1part2}
\begin{question}
    What is 1-1
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    0
\end{solution}
\printsolutions[chapter]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, nowadays you don't have to use `\@addtoreset` but can use `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}`.

Comment: Seems like `exsheets` isn't built for this (if my quick look at the sty was correct, it uses the chapter counter in a sequence to set up its data structure, but doesn't consider the parts). You should contact the package author for a feature request.

Comment: If I understand this correctly than what you want is not supported in `exsheets` and *will* not be supported as it is not developed any longer

Comment: `exsheets`' successor `xsim` would fail here, too. This is worth a feature request there

Comment: Ok, thanks everybody for your comments!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments